# cURL caused page to hang

Tags: php, curl

So I have this piece of function to grab the postal zip within 30 miles of the target zip.

I used this function in my webpage but then I realize sometime the page couldn't finish loading. Once it stuck in loading, opening the url in new tab won't work as well and I have to restart the entire browser just to "resume" it.

After a very long time debugging I found out the culprit was this function.
This function hangs(takes forever to respond and return the result) from time to time on the same parameter.

```
//Get nearby postal zip by using geoname api
//genoname api provide both xml and json version
function getNearByPostalZip($zip){

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?postalcode=".$zip."&country=US&radius=30&username=xxxx&maxRows=100"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);   

$temp = json_decode($output);
$zips = array();
foreach($temp->postalCodes as $key=>$postalcode)
{
    $zips[] = array('zip'=>$postalcode->postalCode,'distance'=>$postalcode->distance);
}
return $zips;
}
```

Comment: Use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT then and some fallback logic.

Comment: I get it, use the timeout to prevent this. But I have a question here, is this problem caused by CURL itself or the API? It's the API right?

Comment: I've tried your code and it works perfectly. it takes 1 second to load. Have you tested it on a different browser ?

Comment: It's kind of random. It hang like 1 out of 100 request and I removed my username in that function too.

Comment: Weird for a serverside script to hang a browser.  Must be something happening on the clientside . . . what is `$zips` being returned to, ajax, or anything like that . . .

Comment: json format, this call is not requested through AJAX. I took that function and put it into a script that do nothing but var_dump the respond returned by the function. I kept refreshing the page and finally I see the page spinning without output anything.